# Coloring background of select list page items

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently trying to create a form within Oracle Apex where the form entries (all select lists) change color based on what data the entry holds.  So far I have a dynamic action that triggers when the page loads that executes the following JS code:

```js
const pageItems = ["P60_C011", "P60_C012", ....., "P60_C049", "P60_C050"]

for (let i = 0; i < pageItems.length; i++){
    if ($v(pageItems[i]) == "Yes"){
        $("#" + pageItems[i]).css("background-color", "#90EE90");
    }

    else if ($v(pageItems[i]) == "No" || $v(pageItems[i]) == "N/A" || $v(pageItems[i]) == "In Progress"){
        $("#" + pageItems[i]).css("background-color", "#F08080");
    }

    else if ($v(pageItems[i]) == "") {
        $("#" + pageItems[i]).css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
}
```

This works great except for a few niche interactions.  For starters the pre-text and post-text background colors are unchanged (they are displayed as blocks within the template options for the page items).  But more importantly, whenever you click on the item (to change its value via a select list), the color returns to the default.  I'd really like the color to remain whatever the dynamic action asks it to be.

Additionally, I'd like for the background to be a different color entirely if the value contained in the page item is changed, but it has not yet been submitted to the form's corresponding table.  I have a few ideas for this but they all seem very tedious and involve separate dynamic actions or code blocks for each of the 40 entries and a more simple solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: you should do this all in CSS

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to go about creating a CSS class with conditions that depend on the value of the item the class is linked with.  If you could point me to a resource that could help me with this I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a dynamic action on this. Instead define a function on page load and use jquery delegated binding to capture any changes:

Function and Global Variable Declaration:

```
function colorSelectLists(){
    const pageItems = ["P185_C1","P185_C2"]
    
    for (let i = 0; i < pageItems.length; i++){
        if ($v(pageItems[i]) == "Y"){
            $("#" + pageItems[i]).css("background-color", "#90EE90");
        }
    
        else if ($v(pageItems[i]) == "N" || $v(pageItems[i]) == "N/A" || $v(pageItems[i]) == "In Progress"){
            $("#" + pageItems[i]).css("background-color", "#F08080");
        }
    
        else if ($v(pageItems[i]) == "") {
            $("#" + pageItems[i]).css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }    
}
```

Execute when Page Loads

```
//initial load
colorSelectLists();
//listener for any changes to adjust the color
$('#P185_C1, #P185_C2').on('change',function(){
    colorSelectLists();
});
```

note that the jquery selector needs to match exactly a comma separated list of ids enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: The initial load seems to work correctly with your method but when I switch responses it simply recolors the cell based on the previous response.  For example if I change a select list from "N" to "Y" the color stays the same as "N" after the change even though the value is different

Comment: That is strange, I just looked at my example where i copied my answer code from and it does work correctly for me. When I set it to Y it turns green and back to red when I change it to N.

Comment: Your code works just fine, I didn't apply yours to my app correctly.  For future users make sure that all the page items in the "Execute when Page Loads" section are in the same string instead of making each page item its own string, and also make sure change is within single quotes

Comment: Added that to the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to call a jquery function when the values from a column in an IG are changed, as opposed to page items as you showed above?

Comment: You can put a dynamic action on change of a column value in an interactive grid and add a true action of type execute javascript. Add ```colorSelectLists();``` as source. I have not tested this, if it doesn't work I suggest you file a new question.